# 404 Error when installing almost every program through terminal

Tags: 13.10

I am quite new to linux (and this forum), and have hardly ever used it before. I am running ubuntu on an android device (using LinuxOnAndroid), and, before someone tells me something about "PPA" I just want to say two things:

1.) I have no idea what that is and

2.) When I get the error that I am having, it does not mention PPA

Anyway, the error I am having is that I can not install programs onto ubuntu. For example, when I try to install chromium browser, it allows ubuntu to ask me if I am sure I want to download the packages, and I agree, but afterwards, almost every file it tried to download states that it had a 404 error and could not be found. I followed most tutorials on fixing this on the internet, even on the forums themselves, but none seemed to work. Here is what it said exactly:

Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/{package name}  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

After it completely fails at trying to install chromium, it then tells me that it failed to fetch some archives, and that I should try apt-get update or try with --fix-missing. These did not work. I tried following the guide here: https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-ubuntudebian-apt-get-404-not-found-package-repository-errors-saucy-raring-quantal-oneiric-natty/?doing_wp_cron=1433464178.3783519268035888671875

But none of these methods worked. I also tried to install Java, but with the same results. I eventually decided to make an account here and ask a question myself. Now I have. If anyone can help me, and if anyone could tell me a tad more about the forum, that would be appreciated.

One more thing, these are the things I am using for linux:

Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander)

LinuxOnAndroid's SMALL ubuntu .img for ARM

That's about it

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried running `do-release-upgrade`, but to no avail. So I have decided to simply downgrade to 12.04. I have also checked my sources.list, and it does not line up with the things you posted, but I can not change it's writing, for I do not have permission, nor do I understand how to grant myself permission. Again, thank you, and now I will put your usernames here: @Germar @geoffW

Comment: `vi /etc/apt/sources.list` and overwrite the content with the following lines `deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security main restricted universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted universe`

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) is in [End of Life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). And so there are no packages available anymore. You should either upgrade to the current release (15.04 Vivid Vervet at time of writing or 14.04.2 for LTS) by running `do-release-upgrade` or try a different image which is still supported like [14.04 Trusty Tahr](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxonandroid/files/Ubuntu/14.04/) or [12.04 Precise Pangolin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxonandroid/files/Ubuntu/12.04/)

Answer (score 0):

I voted up Germar for the answer, because that could be possible, I had the same thing occur while using RaringRingtail. But I do not know when saucy's EndOfLife is. Ubuntu 13.10 SaucySalamander was not a long-term-supported (LTS) version of Ubuntu, and non LTS versions are merely rolling releases to the next rolling-release or long-term-supported version. 
Long story short, your problem is more than likely occurring because they shut the SaucySalamander servers down. If that is not the reason inspect your /etc/apt/sources.list file and see if for some reason there is a mistake with your url's. It should look something like this:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted
```

If the url's are commented out:

```
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted
```

Then it is merely a problem with your /etc/apt/sources.list file and just remove the comments and retry.

More than likely Germar is correct and you should perform the do-release-upgrade.

Good Luck!

Comment: Ubuntu is not a rolling release distribution.

Comment: Take a look into the ubuntu mirrors http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ and you'll find no saucy anymore. It's gone.